# Given n points in a plane, how would I find an equally-spaced collinear triple (if it exists)?

Tags: algorithm

There is obviously the brute-force way to do this, O(n^3). Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: More than likely, yes.  Or, maybe not.

Comment: You should explain a little more about the problem and give maybe a small example.

Comment: Might want to try cross-posting this to the [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) StackExchanges.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to iterate over all pairs of points and check if another point exists exactly in the middle between them. Depending on the representation of the set of points this should result in a better runtime than O(n^3).

Comment: What would be the most efficient representation of the set of points?

Comment: if the coordinates are integers one could use a hash table, otherwise a quadtree maybe.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a hash set of all of the points (N), using the X, Y values as a key.
- Iterate over every pair of points, calculate the mid-point and check if it exists in the hash set (N^2).

> N + N^2 < N^3

Here's a hastily created untested javascript function to demonstrate.

```
function getESCT(points) {
    var hashset = {};
    points.forEach(function(pt) { hashset[pt.x + "," + pt.y] = pt; });
    for(var i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
        var pt1 = points[i];
        for(var j=0; j<points.length; j++) {
            var pt2 = points[j];
            var key = ((pt1.x + pt2.x) / 2) + "," + ((pt1.y + pt2.y) / 2);
            if(hashset[key]) {
                return hashset[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```